# What selector should I use for an element, that depends on hover behavior of a pseudo-element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, hover, pseudo-element

I made a burger-menu with a pseudo-element. Now I need to show a menu, if a pseudo-element is hover. 
I can choose it this way `:.header:hover:before`
But I can't force the menu to depends on it.

It's a structure of html:

```
<header class="header">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.svg" alt="logo" class="logo logo_header"></a>
    <nav class="menu menu_header">It's a menu</nav>
    <div class="contacts-header">Some contacts here</div>
</header>
```

It's CSS:

```
.header:before {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        width: 40px;
        height: 30px;
        background-image: url("../img/icon-burger-menu.svg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: contain;
    }
.menu {
        display: none;
    }

    .header:hover:before **???** {
        display: block;
    }
```

**Is it possible to use a selector in this case?**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQD02.jpg)

Comment: What is the exact effect you want to achieve?
I don't think you can set a :hover on a pseudo element directly with just css.

Comment: I'd like to hover on a burger-menu and to show a menu block. I just don't want to use JS for such an easy case. It looks so easy, if a pseudo-element hover, change display:none on display: block for a menu.

Comment: Use a `<button>` containing an `<img>` with `alt` text and JavaScript to trigger then. Then it will work for people who can't use a mouse or who depend on screen readers. CSS hacks for "easy" *interactions* are just causes of accessibility problems.

Comment: It's good advice, but I can't change html...

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be best here to have your hamburger menu as an actual element, and not a pseudo element.

Pseudo elements have some limitations. One of them is that you can't add ':hover' states to them.

As an added bonus, I think that would be a more developer friendly solution. 
If an other developer needs to alter your code (of you a year from now) he can see the menu in your HTML code. HTML is for markup, CSS is for styling.

The `:before` and `:after` are generally used for minor additions to your code. Not for the important bits like navigation.

Comment: But I can to add a hover behavior ".header:hover:before", or what do you mean? could you explain please? I just can't to connect a pseudo-element with a menu-block. This version for an adaptive, I just don't want to change html-structure for an adaptive version, so I used a pseudo-element here

Comment: When you target `.header:hover:before` you target the :before element when you are hovered over the header. You're not targeting a :hover on only the :before element.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `:hover` to pseudo-elements but pseudo-elements can't affect to their own elements (not with CSS).

Here is a quick summary with the possibilities of elements and pseudo-elements hover states.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 600px;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
div:not(.pseudo-hover):hover::before {
  background-color: pink;
}
div.pseudo-hover:hover::before {
  background-color: pink;
}
div.pseudo-hover::before, div.pseudo-hover-all::before {
  pointer-events: initial;
}
div.pseudo-hover-all {
  pointer-events: none;
}
div::before {
  content: '::before';
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  top: 0;
  right: -60%;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<h3>Hover on element affects to pseudo-element</h3>
<div>Element</div>
<h3>Hover on pseudo-element or element affects to pseudo-element</h3>
<div class="pseudo-hover">Element</div>
<h3>Hover on pseudo-element affects only to pseudo-element</h3>
<div class="pseudo-hover-all">Element</div>
```